# How to show embedded pdf in IE 11 in angular 6 app

Tags: javascript, angular, html

I want to show pdf file (file from external link) embedded in browser.

I have tried html 5 embed tag and object tag. Have also tried using iframe. In chrome everything works but IE 11 does not support it.

Is there any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

Use  and call pdf link directly

```
<div id="pdf">
   <iframe src="...." style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
        <p>It appears your web browser doesn't support iframes.</p>
   </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: In IE 11  pdf it is getting downloaded. its not shown in view